# Given a region in frequency domain highlighted in different color , How can we get that region back in time domain? or location in time domain

Tags: signal-processing, python

I have one signal in frequency domain which has some highlighted portion as an anomaly, What I would like to do is that convert this frequency domain signal with highlighted region into the time series domain and anomaly region as well. Is there any way I can do it. I used the following code for time to frequency domain conversion

```
    '''data = pd.read_csv(path)
    y= fft(data)
    
    sample = len(data)
    N = 96000 # sampling rate
    frequency = np.linspace (0.0, sample, int (N/2))
    y= 2/N * (y[0:np.int (N/2)])'''
```

Comment: If you mean you want the time domain part associated with some portion of the frequency domain, simply set all the terms to zero except the frequencies of interest. Then apply the ifft

Comment: Thank you @RezhaAdrianTanuharja for your answer, could you please tell me is one to one conversion from frequency domain to time domain is possible considering it also has the points which needs to be represented as anomaly

Comment: FFT and IFFT are essentially several scalar multiplication and permutation of a vector, and it's linear operator. So if you want, you can split the frequency domain into vector that is 'normal' and vector that is 'abnormal', apply IFFT to these, and you will get a 'normal' time series and 'abnormal time series.